# Typescript: Why resulting property types merges in interface union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function which accepts two combinations of parameters.
Why resulting type of currentVariation inside function includes all possible variants of keys instead of separate sets from banner or column? And how to solve such problem?
the error could be seen here
[same code on codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-uholqy?file=/index.ts)

```
const bannerVariationMap = {
  default: { label: "Banner (Center)" },
  with_image: { label: "Banner (Right) with image" }
};
export const columnVariationMap = {
  twoColumn: { label: "Two Columns" }
};

type bannerVariationType = typeof bannerVariationMap;
type columnVariationTypes = typeof columnVariationMap;

interface IBlockVariationSelectBanners {
  currentVariation: keyof bannerVariationType;
  variationMap: bannerVariationType;
}

interface IBlockVariationSelectColumns {
  currentVariation: keyof columnVariationTypes;
  variationMap: columnVariationTypes;
}

type IBlockVariationSelect = IBlockVariationSelectBanners | IBlockVariationSelectColumns;

export const variationSelect = ({
  currentVariation,
  variationMap
}: IBlockVariationSelect) => {
  return variationMap[currentVariation].label;
};
```

Comment: Could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV795m)

Comment: This is the same underlying issue as in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) where the compiler does not see the correlation between the union types of `variationMap` and `currentVariation`.  A refactor to use generics is probably needed here; given your example code, I'd probably approach it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/Wok9eW).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The second solution works perfectly.Thank you @jcalz
The first one can't work because it will fault on invocation, because it requests combined map.

Comment: There is another solution, it helps to get rid of error, but it does not give control as solution of jcals:
`
type VariationKeysType = keyof BannerVariationType | keyof ColumnVariationType;

interface IBlockVariationSelect {
  styles: {
    variationSelect: string;
    settingTitle: string;
    changeVariationLink: string;
  };
  currentVariation: VariationKeysType;
  variationMap: Record<string, { image: string }>;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Aside: in what follows, I'm not sure if you want the labels to have [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of just `string`, but if so then you could use [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) as shown here:

```
const bannerVariationMap = {
  default: { label: "Banner (Center)" },
  with_image: { label: "Banner (Right) with image" }
} as const;

export const columnVariationMap = {
  twoColumn: { label: "Two Columns" },
} as const;
```

But it doesn't really matter for your question as asked.

---

The problem with your code is that TypeScript really can't follow the correlation between the types of `variationMap` and `currentVariation` in a single line of code, even though they are [destructured properties of a discriminated union](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).  This limitation is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). To use [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) in TypeScript, you have to check the discriminant *explicitly* against some value, which then narrows the other properties are narrowed as well.  So in order for your current setup to be understandable to the compiler, you'd need to write out redundant code like this:

```
export const variationSelect = ({
  currentVariation,
  variationMap
}: IBlockVariationSelect) => {
  switch (currentVariation) {
    case "default": return variationMap[currentVariation].label;
    case "twoColumn": return variationMap[currentVariation].label;
    case "with_image": return variationMap[currentVariation].label;
  }
}; // okay
```

---

If you don't want to do write redundant code or just suppress the error with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), you could refactor your code so that `variationSelect()` is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), involving [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

Here's one approach:

```
type AllKeys<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
type EitherMap = typeof bannerVariationMap | typeof columnVariationMap;
type VariationLabels = { [K in AllKeys<EitherMap>]: 
  Extract<EitherMap, Record<K, any>>[K]['label'] };
/* type VariationLabels = {
    default: "Banner (Center)";
    with_image: "Banner (Right) with image";
    twoColumn: "Two Columns";
} */
```

Here I've defined a helper utility type `AllKeys<T>` which takes a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of types and produces a union of keys for each member (if you write `keyof (A | B)` you'll only get the keys common to both of them, whereas `AllKeys<A | B>` will give all the keys of `A` and all the keys of `B`).

Then, `VariationLabels` is a mapping from the intended `currentVariation`, with the `label` property in whichever map has that label.  The manipulation with [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) mostly deals with the possibility that the same key will be in multiple maps, and you want a union of labels in that case.

Anyway, now we can define `IBlockVariationSelect` as a *generic* type that depends on the key of `VariationLabels`:

```
type IBlockVariationSelect<K extends keyof VariationLabels> = {
  currentVariation: K, variationMap: { [P in K]: { label: VariationLabels[P] } }
}
```

And now `variationSelect()` is generic in `K` constrained to `keyof VariationLabels`, like this:

```
export const variationSelect = <K extends keyof VariationLabels>({
  currentVariation,
  variationMap
}: IBlockVariationSelect<K>) => {
  return variationMap[currentVariation].label;
};
```

That compiles because now there is a generic correlation between `currentVariation` (type `K`) and `variationMap` (type `{[P in K]: {label: VariationLabels[P]}`).  So `variationMap[currentVariation]` is seen to be of type `{label: VariationLabels[K]}`, and therefore its `label` property is of type `VariationLabels[K]`, which is the return type of the function.

Let's test it:

```
const x = variationSelect(
  { currentVariation: "default", variationMap: bannerVariationMap }
); // okay
// const x: "Banner (Center)"

variationSelect(
  { currentVariation: "default", variationMap: columnVariationMap }
); // error
```

Looks good.  For the first call, the compiler accepts the arguments and produces a value of the proper type.  For the second call, the compiler rejects the arguments because `variationMap` does not contain a property named `default`.

---

But we can simplify even further by making this *more* generic, if you want:

```
export const variationSelect = <
  K extends string, 
  V extends Record<K, { label: string }>
>({ currentVariation, variationMap }: { currentVariation: K, variationMap: V }) => {
  const ret: V[K]['label'] = variationMap[currentVariation].label;
  return ret;
};
```

Here all I've done is require that `variationMap` have a property with key `currentVariation` with a value assignable to  `{label: string}`, and the return type from `variationSelect` is the type of that `label` property.

Using the following definitions, where I add a common key to both maps:

```
const bannerVariationMap = {
  default: { label: "Banner (Center)" },
  with_image: { label: "Banner (Right) with image" },
  other: { label: "Other Banner" }
} as const;

export const columnVariationMap = {
  twoColumn: { label: "Two Columns" },
  other: { label: "Other Column" }
} as const;
```

We can see that this behaves quite similarly as before:

```
const x = variationSelect(
  { currentVariation: "default", variationMap: bannerVariationMap }
); // okay
// const x: "Banner (Center)"

variationSelect(
  { currentVariation: "default", variationMap: columnVariationMap }
); // error
```

And it can even consistently distinguish between the different map labels even if they share a common key:

```
const y = variationSelect(
  { currentVariation: "other", variationMap: columnVariationMap }
); //okay
// const y: "Other Column"
```

The previous version would give you a union like `"Other Banner" | "Other Column"`, which isn't as specific as it could be.  Note that this version does not depend on  `IBlockVariationSelect` and does not care about what `currentVariation` and `variationMap` values might be declared in your code base.  It will accept anything as long as it's internally consistent.  This may or may not be acceptable for your use case.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQzGApgJwGoLQSwVHcAWQQAcYBeGAbwCgYYATFAMwQFcAbKALhpk4I4KTnwBEAISSo0MABQBhFGCjoAlGJgBfADT0YAdxxQAFgH0cAWwQBzFH2oChI8VOTp5AJRw2TUNYbGJjBWtiiaWrRaMAgQMKCQUADctLQoAB6kIGiwCdDxIJzslmBYuPiEYCTkVHQMUAYgCoXFYA5OwqIwYgAqjTDNRSUQEXrRsQWJKbRgCJYoEKQIwCgwACIgCwByIFAA6tkA1jSp9QCepKuI7pjYeATgPRerVFDPICzw0uhl95XVKXOlwKQ1Kdwqj2ecVe70+oFBvwhVTI0wYOBU6DYKxgAEkJJwQMBDoiHmAAMoiFDAKBuGRxOoMeLsNBoZRQEmVPiHFBnD5fG4cyGXQGMgBu4NJ1T41xkgrAT2F+ki+nRqjQWNWeIJRLlFM4VKgg1a9P0DGAzNZKjlXJ5fPhrTlCoWIoY4vKkrIfHtJUdUJFyqBmvxhOJEsqeoNlFxwZ1YfAEeptPQcQAPtHtaH3eHKdSjcNUTAMlkcpN8m6-vGc7AqHIGWaLWy5XpGTBy0jqkq+FqQ7qqwEKAA+E4tiBGKDAYJyc0sxtxsABOuM4CxVZiZhsLhQMR8VlQZlgVtz6oAbWnlvZc4AugA6QSdF1LlfdBpNFolbcwXf7w9Z4hkU8NlaV63s4nAPmaT5iGO5ihHYH5fmgB5th6pAATOQG-mAN53iID6RAwWhJDAAD0xEwCAhwIGcUSpLM8yLMsqwbAsBxoMcDJvMCACiQToNUUacSgfIyj8R5kDAaaCXab5gphAL6IJMAAIKcJwADSPIQAAPD0Q5UD0hbpKoYCMHE7BgIcYAgAYB4APwwNyvKfAZfCoKK6AiopcoADKgdC-DHmpIQHip6maVpPGmHxZADpefBcUZaDLFAEW8Wg1Q6DAnhUtkjBaWpmVIGcA4DoFl7HgA5DhnAVZe2gisRABUMBeXOvmdP5i4MOuHDcK43yyIobLqGI4GBKYFjWHY-U3F4Ph+AE0EhFN4RjS+eZtN0fQgAMMkjP6MCNcRpwtc86Y9nOCYpUFGTGaZDm2p8Pl+Xpw5LoBF6YXwBU-hWyKkO0x4AArBTAalxfw1V8M9HXA3V0T4doJ1FtkuTgGWl1VlG+WGXdcSOXyMMiBAA61qaTLoZ9f3NmKYmkJ252xphV35QO-ZDouCFIXTaHnnK2Ggf6BZ5LA6RRsh2b6tStYU3zc7iD1m5iJlEt-gD-KynT2gBKR5GUdRDC6yLMDpDNMjyEoGJoBoJ2q+SVYy2es5fd0ivcMrv3tp6IIOlrWg62R6BoNkNG0XMCxLNiKlqrMqgnPoKMlsbdtXdjN1Gco93QLgYA2JlGC45ncTZaAaB5T9jhQzA2fojY2glWTLZOxh1Oeyh2jtM3VNIt9Kt09D2uUBz5PG7u0NlZV1W1eLPNd-zIH3uTXOfigyRKsL6OwCJtxyeJtTk27vCQ6BZseENVsaNoNMMNBk1hO0VeSANc2+P443BLB4RX+TuwmOgD8n26AAeSirIJMaAIhKhiHEEWBZE5o0SD7H0Wt94tnWjJABnRxDbV2qCEY38Wy-3-sfLBwDQG4NaJAgi0DSxr30MbMWVAU4O0cHPeWrtWC9S3H3Xe6tt5yn4v7EiZEKJUX0EbTeJtT6DUtmqG2+hmFSygI7D61oOEbndjwv6UokGyW0eJIRusg4h3oZIs4M9mYsNls7P64giEQK0V7dW3o9FOO1kRUioiDbCNoTAM44gQF-1kBtMQqRIhAA)